# I want to insert data into a table using loop I have Multi -D array using PHP

Tags: php

**

> data did not insert into table, please help
>   I am not understand
>   which loop to use
>   I want to insert data into a table using loop I have Multi -D array 
>   using PHP

**

```
<?php
$data = array('eid' => array(124,658,457,145),
                'data' => array('2012/10/12','2012/10/15','2012/10/22','2012/10/02'),
                'name' => array('Chiku','Lipu','Babu','Dipu')
);
foreach($data as $key => $value){   ///////////
        $k = $key;
        $v = $value;
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r ($k);
        echo "<br>";
    foreach($v as $ke => $va){  /////////////
        //echo "<pre>";
        //print_r ($va);
        $ke;
        $va;
        //echo "<pre>";
        print_r ($va);
    }
        $count = count($va);
        echo "<br>";
        echo $count;
}
    echo "<pre>";
    //print_r ($k);
    //echo "<pre>";
    //print_r ($v);
    $k = $k;
    $v = implode('',$v);
    //echo $v;
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','loop');
    $sql = "INSERT INTO loopt (`eid`,`date`,`name` ) VALUES ($v)";
    $exe = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not a best way to do this, but still, you can try following

```html
$data = array('eid' => array(124,658,457,145),
                'data' => array('2012/10/12','2012/10/15','2012/10/22','2012/10/02'),
                'name' => array('Chiku','Lipu','Babu','Dipu')
);


if (isset($data['eid']) && is_array($data['eid']) && sizeof($data['eid']) > 0) 
{
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','loop');

    foreach ($data['eid'] as $key => $value) 
    {
        if (isset($data['data']) && isset($data['data'][$key]) && isset($data['name']) && isset($data['name'][$key]) ) 
        {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO loopt (`eid`,`date`,`name` ) VALUES ($value,$data['data'][$key],$data['name'][$key])";
            $exe = mysqli_query($con,$sql);    

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: also instead of this, you can try to convert your data like 
$data = array(array('eid'=>124,'date'=>'2012/10/12','name'=>'Chiku'),array('eid'=>658,'date'=>'2012/10/15','name'=>'Lipu'),); 
and use foreach on this